# Find the set of all limit points of $\{y= \dfrac{x}{1+|x|} \in \mathbb R \ | \ \text {for all} \ x \in \mathbb R \}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Find the set of all limit points of $\left\{y= \dfrac{x}{1+|x|} \in \mathbb R \ | \ \text {for all} \ x \in \mathbb R \right\}$.

The value of $y$ lies between $(-1,1)$. Therefore, The limit points must be $\{-1,1\}$?
The answer given is $(-1,1)$. Is the answer given correct?

Comment: I assume you meant $\frac x{1+|x|}$ and not $\frac x1 + |x|$. If that's wrong, please edit back.

Comment: I think it should be $[-1,1]$.

Comment: yeah, i think so too.May be then the answer given is wrong.

Comment: As a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, the limit points are $[-1,1]$. As a subset of $(-1,1)$ then limit points are $(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

It is helpful to observe that
$Y(x) = \frac{x}{1 + |x|}$ is a **continuous** function that is defined on the entire real line.

Any continuous function defined on a "connected" set of real numbers has set of limit points equal to the **closed interval between its infimum and supremum.** (By "defined on a connected set",
I just mean, defined on an interval, where the entire real line counts as an interval.)
(To clarify, this is only true if we count $\infty$ and $-\infty$ as possible limit points, although that doesn't come up in this case.)

So we better calculate $\inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}} Y(x)$ and $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} Y(x)$.
The supremum is as $x \to \infty$, $Y(x) \to 1$ from below.
The infemum is as $x \to -\infty$, $Y(x) \to -1$ from above.
Altogether, the set of limit points will therefore be $[-1,1]$.

The answer $(-1,1)$ would be right if we don't allow limit points where $x \to \infty$ or $x \to -\infty$. This seems like a silly thing to do, but do check your book's definition of *limit point* and compare. My definition of *limit point* is: a limit point of a function $Y(x)$ is a limit point of the image of the set, in this case a limit point of $Y(\mathbb{R})$.